# UI does not accept file drops

Tags: python, pyside2

**What I want to do:**

I am trying to create a PySide2/PyQt window which accepts the files dropped on its UI and runs a function.

**Problem:**

UI is not accepting file drops and does not trigger any event function defined. 
[image]

**What I have done so far:**

Below is the trimmed down code of my app where I am loading a .ui-file created in Qt-Designer to load the interface.

- window gets stored in self.window variable.
- self.window has setAcceptDrops(True).
- Event functions are also defined.

-Code

```
from PySide2 import QtUiTools
from PySide2 import QtGui
from PySide2 import QtCore
from PySide2 import QtWidgets

import os,sys
kUiFilePath = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__) , 'uiFile.ui')


class LoadTool(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, uiFilePath):
        self.window = None
        self.app = None
        self.loadUI(uiFilePath)
        self.window.setAcceptDrops(True)
        self.window.show()
        sys.exit(self.app.exec_())

    def dropEvent(self, e):
        print e
        e.accept()

    def dragEnterEvent(self, e):
        print e
        e.accept()

    def dragMoveEvent(self, e):
        print e
        e.accept()


    def loadUI(self, uiFilePath):        
        self.app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
        super(LoadTool, self).__init__()
        self.window = QtUiTools.QUiLoader().load(uiFilePath)

LoadTool(kUiFilePath)
```

UI file code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>ShellExport</class>
 <widget class="QDialog" name="ShellExport">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>399</width>
    <height>520</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="mouseTracking">
   <bool>false</bool>
  </property>
  <property name="acceptDrops">
   <bool>true</bool>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>Dialog</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QGroupBox" name="groupBox">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>10</x>
     <y>10</y>
     <width>381</width>
     <height>501</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
   <property name="acceptDrops">
    <bool>true</bool>
   </property>
   <property name="title">
    <string>Device Status</string>
   </property>
   <widget class="QGroupBox" name="groupBox_2">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>10</x>
      <y>30</y>
      <width>361</width>
      <height>111</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="acceptDrops">
     <bool>true</bool>
    </property>
    <property name="title">
     <string>Deploy Fbx</string>
    </property>
    <widget class="QLineEdit" name="lineEdit">
     <property name="geometry">
      <rect>
       <x>10</x>
       <y>50</y>
       <width>341</width>
       <height>20</height>
      </rect>
     </property>
    </widget>
    <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton">
     <property name="geometry">
      <rect>
       <x>270</x>
       <y>80</y>
       <width>75</width>
       <height>23</height>
      </rect>
     </property>
     <property name="text">
      <string>Deploy fbx</string>
     </property>
    </widget>
    <widget class="QLabel" name="label_2">
     <property name="geometry">
      <rect>
       <x>10</x>
       <y>30</y>
       <width>47</width>
       <height>13</height>
      </rect>
     </property>
     <property name="text">
      <string>Fbx path</string>
     </property>
    </widget>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QGraphicsView" name="graphicsView">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>20</x>
      <y>150</y>
      <width>201</width>
      <height>91</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
   </widget>
  </widget>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

Comment: share uiFile.ui file

Comment: @eyllanesc: thanks for taking a look at it. Added .ui file code

Comment: What type of files are you dragging ?, I tried with a .txt and I do not see the rejection icon.

Comment: For some reason, on my end, it is rejecting .txt file as well

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/reXyfcW

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you?

```
from PySide2.QtUiTools import QUiLoader
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget
from PySide2.QtCore import QFile

from contextlib import closing
import sys


class DropWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(DropWidget, self).__init__(parent)

    def dropEvent(self, e):
        print("Drop", e)
        e.accept()

    def dragEnterEvent(self, e):
        print("dragEnter", e)
        e.accept()

    def dragMoveEvent(self, e):
        print("dragMove", e)
        e.accept()


class MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()

        self.ui_loader = QUiLoader()
        self.ui_loader.registerCustomWidget(DropWidget)
        self.ui_file = QFile('uiFile2.ui')
        with closing(self.ui_file) as self.qt_file:
            if self.qt_file.open(QFile.ReadOnly):
                self.main_win = self.ui_loader.load(self.qt_file)
            else:
                print('Failed to read UI')

    def show(self):
        self.main_win.show()


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
main = MainWindow()
main.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

and

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>800</width>
    <height>600</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="DropWidget" name="centralwidget">
   <property name="acceptDrops">
    <bool>true</bool>
   </property>
   <widget class="QGroupBox" name="groupBox">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>0</x>
      <y>0</y>
      <width>381</width>
      <height>501</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="acceptDrops">
     <bool>true</bool>
    </property>
    <property name="title">
     <string>Device Status</string>
    </property>
    <widget class="QGroupBox" name="groupBox_2">
     <property name="geometry">
      <rect>
       <x>10</x>
       <y>30</y>
       <width>361</width>
       <height>111</height>
      </rect>
     </property>
     <property name="acceptDrops">
      <bool>true</bool>
     </property>
     <property name="title">
      <string>Deploy Fbx</string>
     </property>
     <widget class="QLineEdit" name="lineEdit">
      <property name="geometry">
       <rect>
        <x>10</x>
        <y>50</y>
        <width>341</width>
        <height>20</height>
       </rect>
      </property>
     </widget>
     <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton">
      <property name="geometry">
       <rect>
        <x>270</x>
        <y>80</y>
        <width>75</width>
        <height>23</height>
       </rect>
      </property>
      <property name="text">
       <string>Deploy fbx</string>
      </property>
     </widget>
     <widget class="QLabel" name="label_2">
      <property name="geometry">
       <rect>
        <x>10</x>
        <y>30</y>
        <width>47</width>
        <height>13</height>
       </rect>
      </property>
      <property name="text">
       <string>Fbx path</string>
      </property>
     </widget>
    </widget>
    <widget class="QGraphicsView" name="graphicsView">
     <property name="geometry">
      <rect>
       <x>20</x>
       <y>150</y>
       <width>201</width>
       <height>91</height>
      </rect>
     </property>
    </widget>
   </widget>
  </widget>
 </widget>
 <customwidgets>
  <customwidget>
   <class>DropWidget</class>
   <extends>QWidget</extends>
   <header>dropwidget.h</header>
   <container>1</container>
  </customwidget>
 </customwidgets>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

Using UI files comes with several pitfalls:
 1. The main UI object is the object returned by the loader. The posted code defines event methods not for the loaded object but for the load tool
 2. Custom widget must be registered with ui_loader.registerCustomWidget before they can be used
3. Loading the UI file stops after an error

I am not sure, if this can be adapted to QDialog
Please not, that this code is for Python 3.6